# WheelView not filling parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-wheel

I am using [Yuri Kanivets's WheelView control](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) and I am finding that it is not filling the parent view even though the layout XML is specifying it to do so.

Here is an image of what I mean:

[image]

Here is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/picker_bar">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/repeatButton"
                android:textColor="#FFF"                
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/picker_button_selected"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Repeat"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/DelayButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/picker_button_unselected"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"  
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"  
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"         
                android:text="Delay"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/doneButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/picker_button_unselected"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Done"/>               
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/repeat_view"/>
        <include layout="@layout/delay_view"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the repeat/delay view XML (they are both pretty much the same):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wheelRepeat"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"     
        android:orientation="horizontal">
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/activeRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>             
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/minsRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/secsRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>                 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I'm adding the view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

            ...
```

I've looked through the WheelView source, but it's not obvious where the width of the entire control is being set and if the wheel control is somehow also controlling the width of the parent layout.

This is running on the latest SDK.  Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: I can see no connection between the wheel picker and the XML you've posted.  Have you posted the correct file?

Comment: @Simon I added the repeat/delay view XML files.  Please let me know if you need to see anything else

Comment: Are there two views, one for repeat and one for delay? If so, there could be an ID conflict.

Comment: In all the `WheelView` views you have, specify `android:layout_width=0dp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LinearLayout` which contains the three `desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView` has `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, but the WheelViews themselves have:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

That being said and if I understand the question correctly means, that if the width of the three Wheels is less that the width of the `parent` (in this case the `LinearLayout` which contains the three `desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView`) - then you'll have to either strech the Wheels of fill the `LinearLayout` with a solid color (black for example) to hide what's behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution to g00dy (although he's completely right)-  if you set the width of each of the wheels to 0dp and set their layout_weight=1, the 3 will stretch to take up an equal portion of the screen.  If you don't want them equal, set them in the ratio you want.

Comment: Great alternative!  I'll give this a try

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:weightSum="3"      // add weight sum here 
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"     
        android:orientation="horizontal">
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/activeRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>             //weights here
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/minsRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>              //weights here
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/secsRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>              //weights here    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Change your wheel layout like this

Answer (score 0):

Try a layout like this for your repeat/delay view xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wheelRepeat"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"     
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/activeRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>             
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/minsRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>
       <desiderata.ihunt.resources.WheelView 
            android:id="@+id/secsRepeat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>                 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will make the widget fill the screen width and you can adjust the width ratio by tweaking the layout weight. In case you dont need the widget to fill entire screen in landscape mode, you can use wrap content for the width of the parent linear layout.